# How to horizontally distribute inputs inside the parent?

Tags: html, css

I have five `select` inputs and want to distribute them horizontally inside the parent div.
This code doesn't work:

```
<div id="divtable">
    <select class="abc"></select>
    <select class="abc"></select>
    <select class="abc"></select>
    <select class="abc"></select>
    <select class="abc"></select>
</div>
```

css

```
#divtable{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border:thin solid red;
}
.abc{
    display:table-cell;
    width:17%;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:3px;
    border:thin solid #999;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AVhXN/)

Comment: The fiddle works for me!? (firefox) You can also try `.abc { display:inline-block; }`

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus, I use firefox 23. What do you see? Is the last element aligned right with parent and are the spacing equal?

Comment: @SunSky: I see you have already accepted an answer. Just out of curiosity, did you try setting `width:20%;` for `.abc`? It will distribute them evenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, a `display: table-*` structure requires a full valid (fake) table structure - with corresponding `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` elements to work properly. (Also I'd not expect putting `display: table-cell` on an input element to work in the first place.)

This works:

```
<div id="divtable">
   <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">
    <select class="abc"></select>
    </div>

    ....

  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AVhXN/2/

Although I personally would really use tables before resorting to this - this insane div soup is no more semantically useful than a table, IMO.

Comment: Pekka, I agree, it seems i must draw a table. it's terrible. I expected there is something like: `distribute:horizontally;`. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change the abc class display to **inline** :

```
.abc{
    display:inline;
    width:17%;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:3px;
    border:thin solid #999;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

Comment: shaftpolls, I just tried in ff and Chrome. The last input is not right aligned with parent.

Comment: Oh sorry but I was not aware of that requirement since you did not mention it on your initial question.